# Problem opening password encrypted .docx file on Word 2003

Tags: compatibility, microsoft-office-2003

I am having  a problem opening a .docx file on my Word 2003. I have installed the Compatibility pack for 2007 but when i try to open this particular file, I receive the error "Word experienced an error trying to open the file. Try these suggestions. 1. Check the file permissions for the document, 2. Make sure there is sufficient free memory and disk space, 3. Open the file with the Text Recovery converter.

I do not think it is any of the errors as I am able to open it on a different PC with Word 2003 as well. I also do not have any issues opening any non-password encrypted .docx files.

Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Most posts on the internet relate to "open and repair" but as mentioned, I am able to open this file on another PC without any problems.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 0):

On the other PC, open the file and then save it (to a new name), and see if that helps.

Also try a repair on the Office installation.

Comment: Thanks Richard. I have already tried Office repair. Also tried renaming but from the same PC since it doesn't actually resolve the issue if I opened it from another PC and renamed it since the file is specifically meant for him and he is the only one who will be given the password to decrypt.